# Showing $X_n\to0$ pointwise but $E(X_n)\not\to0$

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, expected-value, pointwise-convergence

So the question is, for Lebesgue probability space $(\mathbb{R}, B(\mathbb{R}), \lambda)$, define $$X_n(\omega) =  
\begin{cases}n^2\omega, &0\leq \omega \leq \frac{1}{n}, \\   2n-n^2\omega, &\frac{1}{n} \leq \omega \leq \frac{2}{n}, \\  0, &\frac{2}{n} \leq \omega \leq 1 
\end{cases}$$
I am tasked to show that $X_n$ is point-wise convergent to $0$, as $n$ tends to $\infty$, while  $EX_n \not\rightarrow EX$.

So for the first task my first thought was to using the definition of pointwise convergence, i.e., $\forall \ \epsilon>0,$ there exists an index $N$ such that $\forall n>N, \ \ |X_n-X|< \epsilon$ at each critical point, i.e., $ \omega_0=1/n, \ \omega_1=2/n $ as each function defined in each boundary is linear function therefore continuous.

However, considering in the case of $X$, where $n$ tended to $\infty$, as you can see I cannot write the function because $n$ exploded, and since the fact that $\omega_0, \omega_1$ are dependent on $n$ may prevent me to proceed this way? or because $n$ already tended to $\infty$ I can just consider $X=0$ $\forall \omega$?

Also any hint to proceed with the first and the second part would be greatly appreciated. I think $EX$ would be evaluated to $0$. so I need to show that $EX_n \not\rightarrow 0$ at the essence,  but I am not sure how am I gonna do that.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you even talking about continuity?  What does that have to do with the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine pointwise convergence you have to examine the sequence $(X_n(\omega))$ for each fixed $\omega$ and observe what happens as $n\to\infty$. That is, you fix an $\omega\in[0,1]$ and study the sequence of real numbers $(X_n(\omega))$. To do so you have to observe how the functions $X_n$ change as $n$ increases. In particular, you'll see that if your fixed $\omega$ is greater than zero, then for all large enough $n$ the region $[0,\frac2n]$ where $X_n$ is nonzero eventually slides to the left of $\omega$.  In other words, for all large enough $n$, $X_n(\omega)=0$. The case $\omega=0$ is handled separately. In either case you will have shown that $X_n(\omega)\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

As for your second part, you need to compute $E(X_n)$, which is the area under $X_n$, for each $n$. This is a straightforward exercise in integration.  As for $E(X)$, this is zero since $X=0$.

It will help to draw a picture of $X_n$. Observe that the graph of $X_n$ as a function of $\omega$ is a tent with base $[0,\frac2n]$ and peak of height $n$ at $\omega=\frac1n$, and zero elsewhere. (I'm assuming in the second case you have a typo and the formula should be $2n-n^2\omega$.)

Comment: Thank you! I worked out the solution thanks to your advice. :)